# how to traverse two hashes simultaneously ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hashes and I want to traverse both of them. How can I traverse them simultaneously.

```
hash1 = {"key1" =>["value1","value11"], "key2" => ["value2","value21"]}
hash2= {"key3" => ["value3","value32"], "key4" => ["value4","value42"]}

hash1.each do |k1,v1|
  hash2.each do |k2,v2|
    #do something with v1 and v2 (which are arrays themselves and get ["value1","value11"] and ["value3","value32"], then ["value1","value11"] and ["value4","value42"] in the first iteration of hash 1 and ["value2","value21"]and ["value3","value32"], then ["value2","value21"]and ["value4","value42"] in the second iteration of hash1 )
  end
end
```

This is what I'm doing right now. Is there any other idiomatic or better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't think there is anything wrong with how you are doing it. If you want a more flexible way, you can take the Cartesian product of their key arrays and iterate over it...

```
all_key_combos = hash1.keys.product(hash2.keys)
=> [["key1", "key3"], ["key1", "key4"], ["key2", "key3"], ["key2", "key4"]] 

all_key_combos.each do |k1,k2|
  #do something with k1 and k2
end
```

to get the values from this, a simple map would build an array, not knowing what output you want, makes things difficult, but perhaps this will point you in the right direction?

```
all_key_combos.map { |k1,k2| [hash1[k1], hash2[k2]] }
 => [[["value1", "value11"], ["value3", "value32"]], [["value1", "value11"], ["value4", "value42"]], [["value2", "value21"], ["value3", "value32"]], [["value2", "value21"], ["value4", "value42"]]]
```

if you wanted to get their product instead-

```
all_key_combos.map { |k1,k2| hash1[k1].product(hash2[k2]) }
 => [[["value1", "value3"], ["value1", "value32"], ["value11", "value3"], ["value11", "value32"]], [["value1", "value4"], ["value1", "value42"], ["value11", "value4"], ["value11", "value42"]], [["value2", "value3"], ["value2", "value32"], ["value21", "value3"], ["value21", "value32"]], [["value2", "value4"], ["value2", "value42"], ["value21", "value4"], ["value21", "value42"]]]
```

The possibilities are endless :)

Comment: hey, thanks. Please see the edit in the question, i need values which are arrays